# How do I get the DropDown selection from a Command Button in ArcObjects?

Tags: c#, esri, arcobjects, icommand, arcmap

I have a dropdown and a Icommand button in the same toolbar in ArcMap.  I can't seem to get access to the dropdowns selection when I am using the command button.

How can I find the dropdown so I can find out what the user just selected?

Thanks

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Drop Down with this code...  Then I dove a little Deeper to pull the dropdown out.

```
var commandBars= m_application.Document.CommandBars;
           ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID pUID = new UIDClass();
           pUID.Value = "{A6D2046E-F92C-440f-B54B-91899B4F667E}";
           var commmandItem = commandBars.Find(pUID, false, false);
```

Then the Dropdown was at:

```
(ComboBox)((LOSBaseCampExample.LOSSurroundBaseCampControl)(commmandItem.Command)).Controls[0])
```

Note: LOSBaseCampExample.LOSSurroundBaseCampControl was the name of MY tool...  Your will be different.

Comment: Hard to understand. Not Clear

Answer (score 1):

If your dropdown is within a command that implements IToolControl, you should be able to use ICommandbars.Find to find the command, then cast it to MyToolControl, then use MyToolControl.Selection.  Selection is a method you'll need to implement that accesses the contained dropdown.

Another (more MVC-ish) way is to have the IToolControl update a property on a custom IExtension (e.g. MyExtension.MyProperty), which is implemented to raise an event when the property has changed so that other tools can be in synch.